# How to increase speed of google cloud functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

What is the best way to see where the hiccups are in function speeds?

I know cloud functions deal with cold starts, however, as far as debugging goes, what is the best way to see where the lag is at?

Currently coding in python so any tips in that language would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look on [Tips & Tricks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) that describes the best practices for designing, implementing, testing and deploying Cloud Function.  The [performance](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance) section describes best practices for optimizing performance.

Comment: @Mahboob - Post that as the answer. Very good information.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look on [tips & tricks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) that describes the best practices for designing, implementing, testing and deploying Cloud Function. To summarize, you should consider the following:

- Write idempotent functions
- Ensure HTTP functions send an HTTP response
- Do not start background activities
- Always delete temporary files

The [performance](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance) section describes best practices for optimizing performance. On your case you should:

- Use dependencies wisely
- Use global variables to reuse objects in future invocations
- Do lazy initialization of global variables

Also, here's an additional resource [to understand cold boot time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY).